# URLs getting cropped

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Reviewing access logs we've noticed Google PageSpeed Insights crops long URLs at around 70 chars and an ellipsis is appended. This results in a 404. Example:

```
8.8.8.8 - - [17/Sep/2020:10:32:22 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2016/06/petey-peeking-through-d%E2%80%A6 HTTP/1.1" 404 4650 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Moto G (4)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4143.7 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse"
```

On sites with many long URLs this causes a lot of 404s, which negatively impacts WordPress sites for example as they handle 404s via PHP. I presume it will also result in incomplete/incorrect test analysis and results. I can't seem to find any information about this online. Is it intended behavior?

Additional examples:

```
66.249.93.34 - - [17/Sep/2020:14:15:20 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/09/test-picture-with-a-very-very-very-long-name-1024x402.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 17896 "https://wpland.se/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Moto G (4)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4143.7 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse"
```

```
66.249.93.34 - - [17/Sep/2020:14:17:33 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/09/test-picture-with-a-very-very%E2%80%A6 HTTP/1.1" 404 4925 "http://wpland.se/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4143.7 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse"
```

Comment: please provide a publicly accessible URL and I will happily have a look, however this is not something that I have ever seen and worked with sites with very long URLs before (200+ characters).

Comment: We've reproduced it on sereral sites but you can check this one for example: https://wpland.se/. To clarify, it's the included resource URLs that get cropped. Strangely enough we found one instance of the URL not being cropped. I've added examples in the original post.

Comment: Interestingly this appears to be your largest contentful paint, you could have stumbled upon a bug here as I cant see anything immediately obvious, I will have a proper look this evening for you. can you see if this the case on other sites, that Largest Contentful Paint causes the error (and is it only 1 error per run or do you get multiple?)

Comment: We do get multiple on most runs. I added a few more images to the testpage. As far as I can tell we get a broken request for each image. Full log from the PageSpeed run here: https://pastebin.com/mzmJqvMp

Comment: Having had a look at the pastebin it does look like your image (which is the Largest Contentful Paint) is causing the issue. The reason you get multiple is because it is trying to grab all of the variations of the image because you use the `<picture>` element. It definitely looks to be a bug from what I can tell as I couldn't replicate it using different screen / user agent combinations. I would raise the issue on the [Google Lighthouse Repository](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) and see if they have a fix for it.

Comment: Thanks Graham! Appreciate your input here. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue, this function seems to truncate the urls:

```js
   function getOuterHTMLSnippet(element,ignoreAttrs=[],snippetCharacterLimit=500){const ATTRIBUTE_CHAR_LIMIT=75;try{if(element instanceof ShadowRoot){element=element.host;}
const clone=element.cloneNode();ignoreAttrs.forEach(attribute=>{clone.removeAttribute(attribute);});let charCount=0;for(const attributeName of clone.getAttributeNames()){if(charCount>snippetCharacterLimit){clone.removeAttribute(attributeName);}else{let attributeValue=clone.getAttribute(attributeName);if(attributeValue.length>ATTRIBUTE_CHAR_LIMIT){attributeValue=attributeValue.slice(0,ATTRIBUTE_CHAR_LIMIT-1)+'…';clone.setAttribute(attributeName,attributeValue);}
charCount+=attributeName.length+attributeValue.length;}}
const reOpeningTag=/^[\s\S]*?>/;const[match]=clone.outerHTML.match(reOpeningTag)||[];if(match&&charCount>snippetCharacterLimit){return match.slice(0,match.length-1)+' …>';}
return match||'';}catch(_){return`<${element.localName}>`;}};
```

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/11465